# List expression of tuples concerning Celcius to Fahrenheit transposition in given array of degrees in Python

Tags: python, list, tuples

Im trying to write a simple list expression to print a list of tuples of (C, F) where C is degree of temperatre in Celcius from -20 to 100 in steps of 5 , and F is corresponding temperature in Fahrenheit. It seems pretty easy, though I'd like to write the code as a one liner. Maybe someone has and idea, it shouldn't be a big deal. Thanks

```
listExpression  = [ (C,F) for c in range(-20, 100, 5)and F=32+9/5 *C ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the calculation to the second element of the tuple in the list-comp, eg:

```
listExpression = [ (C, C * 1.8 + 32) for C in range(-20, 100, 5)]
```

The only name you can have available in the list comprehension is `C` which comes from the output of what `range(-20, 100, 5)` yields when iterated over, so you compute `F` but just calculating on `C` directly for the 2nd element of the tuple.

Answer (score 0):

Using `lambda`:

```
list(map(lambda x: (x, x*1.8+32) , range(-20, 100, 5)))
```